# One line string iterator; AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right now this works:

```
for x in clean_spaces:

    final_qry = final_qry.replace(x, ' ')`
```

`clean_spaces` is a list of regex group extracted multi-character whitespace values `(\s\s+)` to be replaced in a output string with a single space.

`final_qry` is a SQL query being modified by other actions.

I'd liked to have a cleaner one-line statement like so:

```
final_qry = (final_qry.replace(x, ' ') for x in clean_spaces)
```

However when trying to use that and a similar statement after it, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Is there a way to make the for...in...:...\n...[action] statement into one line without this error?

Comment: No one-line solution is cleaner than the two-line solution.

Comment: maybe you would use `re.sub("\\s+","",final_qry)`

Comment: The comment by @Onyambu is probably the right way to do this. But, if you really want a one liner of what you are doing, then you need to use reduce from functools as `final_qry = reduce((lambda x, y: x.replace(y, ' ')), clean_spaces, final_qry)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

> final_qry = (final_qry.replace(x, ' ') for x in clean_spaces)

`final_qry` is no longer the SQL query it used to be, but a generator expression.

Consider this (a bit simplified) session:

```
$ python
>>> clean_spaces="cd"
>>> final_qry="abcdefg"
>>> final_qry
'abcdefg'
>>> final_qry = (final_qry.replace(x, ' ') for x in clean_spaces)
>>> final_qry
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f85d2828960>
>>> list(final_qry)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I think you won't be able to solve your problem this way. Use the solution proposed by @laylog:

```
final_qry = reduce((lambda x, y: x.replace(y, ' ')), clean_spaces, final_qry)
```